# How to CRUD at angular 7 using fullCalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I need to add events to my calendar via an onscreen form, I have no idea how to do this, the events had to contain edit and delete options as well. I am using angular 7 and calendar and FullCalendar, please does anyone have an exemplow project?

Comment: fullCalendar doesn't provide a form for you to add events. You can write that yourself. It does provide the "select" callback which allows users to choose the period of time the event should cover. If you want to capture more data than that you'll need to make your own form for that. Once you've captured everything then you can add it to the calendar with the "addEvent" method. I suggest you read through the fullCalendar documentation on the website if you're unsure what methods, options etc exist

Answer (score 0):

for a CRUD you need to set a backend too, in order to store the data in a database, I recommend you search tutorials on youtube, some good chanels is traversyMedia, Fireship and Nick Raboy's channel
best!

Comment: I'm already in the database, I need to add events to the calendar

Comment: can you paste me the tag are you setting for the calendar on HTML? we must start from there

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the [FullCalendar Angular Example Project](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/angular)

```
git clone https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects.git
cd fullcalendar-example-projects/angular
npm install
```

Build commands

```
npm run build # build to a directory
npm run start # continously build, as a server
```

Or try to use this [ngx-fullcalendar Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-fullcalendar).